# How do I use 'getelementsbyclassname' when there's a number of the same class name?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to parse an innertext with getelementsbyclassname on 'span' tag. But there were several different inner texts that matches with the same class name. How do I have to parse the inner text?

https://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=063760 -> is the internet explorer document that I'm trying to parse from.

I want to get the specific inner text '15,550' which is the yesterday's closed market price.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwT9g.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer example code below may help you to find inner text = 15,550.

```
Sub demo()
Dim element As IHTMLElement
Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim val, val1 As String
Dim html As HTMLDocument
val = "15,550"


Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True

ie.Navigate "https://finance.naver.com/item/sise_day.nhn?code=063760"
'Wait until IE has loaded the web page

Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE


DoEvents

Loop

Set html = ie.document

Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("tah p11")

Dim count As Long
Dim erow As Long
count = 1
For Each element In elements
If element.className = "tah p11" Then
erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
val1 = html.getElementsByClassName("tah p11")(count).innerText

If val = val1 Then
Cells(erow, 1) = html.getElementsByClassName("tah p11")(count).innerText

End If
count = count + 1
End If
Next element
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

This is just a sample code for your reference. Further, you can try to modify the code to get desired output.

Answer (score 0):

When targeting within a table utilize row and column indices via [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) css selector. You want 4th row, 2nd column. I use css selectors as a faster method given modern websites are optimized for this.

```
ie.document.querySelector(".type2 tr:nth-of-type(4) td:nth-of-type(2)").innerText
```

You can simply shorten to

```
tr:nth-of-type(4) td:nth-of-type(2)
```

as first table with this co-ordinate on the page.

I couldn't see anything useful but maybe also check the [APIs](https://developers.naver.com/docs/common/openapiguide/apilist.md#%EB%B9%84%EB%A1%9C%EA%B7%B8%EC%9D%B8-%EB%B0%A9%EC%8B%9D-%EC%98%A4%ED%94%88-api).